# Do we use a preposition or not in "What year did you buy your car (in)?"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Do we use a preposition "in" in this sentence?
Or we just skip it?

> What year did you buy your car **in**?

Comment: What year did you buy your car? I bought my car in [year]. The prepositions go with answers. Where is John? John is at home.

Comment: It's optional, but at least *some* native speakers will include preposition ***in*** at the *beginning* of the utterance, rather than the end. Dunno if that's because they're still frightened of their pedantic English teacher who told them they mustn't end a sentence with a preposition - utter nonsense ***up with which Churchill famously would not put***.

Comment: @Lambie But in a sentence "What city are you from" a preposition "from" appears in both question and answer - I am from Berlin. What is the difference?

Comment: It is always *In what year did you buy your car?*.  Ending this sort of sentence with a preposition always jars on the ear.

Comment: @Chenmunka But why? In other questions we use different prepositions(e.g. What city are you from). Is there a grammatical explanation?

Comment: @Lambie But I need the preposition - "I bought my car **in** 2020. "

Comment: @Lambie You said that the answer is related to the statement form. The statement form - I bought my car **in** 2020 - has a preposition(**in**). Why, in one case, we put a preposition and don't do the same thing in another case?

Comment: @Lambie, to be fair to John, I'm confused as well. I wonder if you've mixed up references to "question form" and "statement form" at various points. For example, you said "With the car, you don't need a preposition in the statement like you do with Where are you from." Statement? Question? Not sure what you are comparing.

Comment: @PeterKirkpatrick "With the car, you don't need a preposition in the statement like you do with Where are you from." RIght: I bought my car last year.

Comment: You're saying that when you write a statement about something happening at a point in time (buying a car), it can be done without using the preposition **in**. I get it. Now I'm inviting you to get my point: In the first half of the sentence I just quoted, your argument refers to the word **statement**; but you then compare that statement with a **question**: "...like you do with **where are you from**". I can see why that might be confusing to some people.

Answer (score 1):

I bought my car **in 2020**. [statement form]

QUESTION FORM:
**To ask the question, you do not need to use a preposition.**

**When** did you buy your car?

Of course, **you are welcome to use the more awkward**:
What year did you buy your car in?   [not great sounding]
Or
In what year did you buy your car? [stilted]

in [year] is adverbial.

WHEREAS:

I'm from Oslo.
To ask the question, you have to use the preposition or you cannot ask it.

**Where are you from?**

from Oslo is a prepositional phrase.